# Problema com comando "set" do batch

Tags: cmd, batch

Boa tarde. Eu estava fazendo uma programação muito simples, em geral, serve simplesmente para colocar os números que o usuário colocar (10 números) em ordem crescente, porém algo estranho acontece já nessa parte

```
set /p NM9=
set /p NM10=

:CICLO
if %NM10% EQU %NM9% (
    goto IGUAL1
)
if %NM10% LEQ %NM9% (
    set /a VAR=%NM9%
    set /a NM9=%NM10%
    set /a NM10=%VAR%
)
```

Após dar um echo no começo do ciclo, diz que os valores NM9 e NM10 são "1". Vocês conseguem achar o problema? Eu desconfio que é a parte do "VAR", ou talvez algum problema na montagem das linhas. Obrigado.

Comment: Posta o código todo ... o único problema que tem  esse  código é que se NM10 for igual a NM9, ele não vai achar o rótulo IGUAL1, porque você não o criou.

Comment: Cristian eu coloquei como uma resposta à minha pergunta o código todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> O problema é que você está tentando fazer atribuição de valor e soma
>   dentro de um argumento de um comando que utiliza parênteses, utilizando porcentagens nas variáveis, e dessa forma, só se chama variáveis fora dos parênteses de condições **IF** e de comando **FOR**
>
> como resolver isso?
>
> utilize esse comando no começo do código `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`
>
> e altere as porcentagens das variáveis que está chamando para pontos
>   de exclamação, ou seja: uma variável `%VAR%` ficará assim: `!VAR!`
>
> faça as devidas alterações, teste o código e comente aqui se deu
>   certo, blz?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente agora, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cls
set /a VAR=0
set /p NM1=
set /p NM2=
set /p NM3=
set /p NM4=
set /p NM5=
set /p NM6=
set /p NM7=
set /p NM8=
set /p NM9=
set /p NM10=

:CICLO
if %NM10% EQU %NM9% (
    goto IGUAL1
)
if %NM10% LEQ %NM9% (
    set /a VAR=%NM9%
    set /a NM9=%NM10%
    set /a NM10=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL1
if %NM9% EQU %NM8% (
    goto IGUAL2
)
if %NM9% LEQ %NM8% (
    set /a VAR=%NM8%
    set /a NM8=%NM9%
    set /a NM9=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL2
if %NM8% EQU %NM7% (
    goto IGUAL3
)
if %NM8% LEQ %NM7% (
    set /a VAR=%NM7%
    set /a NM7=%NM8%
    set /a NM8=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL3
if %NM7% EQU %NM6% (
    goto IGUAL4
)
if %NM7% LEQ %NM6% (
    set /a VAR=%NM6%
    set /a NM6=%NM7%
    set /a NM7=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL4
if %NM6% EQU %NM5% (
    goto IGUAL5
)
if %NM6% LEQ %NM5% (
    set /a VAR=%NM5%
    set /a NM5=%NM6%
    set /a NM6=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL5
if %NM5% EQU %NM4% (
    goto IGUAL6
)
if %NM5% LEQ %NM4% (
    set /a VAR=%NM4%
    set /a NM4=%NM5%
    set /a NM5=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL6
if %NM4% EQU %NM3% (
    goto IGUAL7
)
if %NM4% LEQ %NM3% (
    set /a VAR=%NM3%
    set /a NM3=%NM4%
    set /a NM4=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL7
if %NM3% EQU %NM2% (
    goto IGUAL8
)
if %NM3% LEQ %NM2% (
    set /a VAR=%NM2%
    set /a NM2=%NM3%
    set /a NM3=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL8
if %NM2% EQU %NM1% (
    goto IGUAL9
)
if %NM2% LEQ %NM1% (
    set /a VAR=%NM1%
    set /a NM1=%NM2%
    set /a NM2=%VAR%
    goto CICLO 
)

:IGUAL9
cls
echo %NM1% %NM2% %NM3% %NM4% %NM5% %NM6% %NM7% %NM8% %NM9% %NM10%
pause
```

O código todo.